# Javascript Passing Parameters When Clicked on Link On Another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, parameter-passing

I have a slider I have implemented on my site and wanted to land on a specific value when clicking on a link on another page:

Here is the script and the parameter I would like to change:

```
$("#screeningSlider").ionRangeSlider({
    hide_min_max: true,
    keyboard: true,
    from: 20,
    min: 1,
    max: 2000,
    step: 0,
    grid_num: 4,
    prettify_separator: ",",
    postfix: " Units",
    max_postfix: "+",
    force_edges: true,

});
```

So when on another page, I'd like to click on a button that would allow me to land on this page, But the parameter FROM to be 10 instead of the default value above. This should only occur when selecting from that specific button.

Here is my site that has the slider: http://therrd.com/screening.html#tenant-Screening

Comment: can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: You could probably just pass a URL parameter and then use javascript to get and set it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use server side for that, you can do it this way

[**EDITED**]

1 - set the link

```
<a href="yourpage.html?slide=10">Go</a>
```

2 - set your function in yourpage.html

```
  vals = {max: 100, min: 0, def: 20} //use your own values here for max min and def
  var param = window.location.href.split("slide=");
  slide = isNaN(param[param.length - 1]) || 
          param[param.length - 1] > vals.max ||
          param[param.length - 1] < vals.min ? vals.def : param[param.length - 1];
          //check if there is a url param, if it's a number and if it's in range      

  $("#screeningSlider").ionRangeSlider({
        hide_min_max: true,
        keyboard: true,
        from: slide,
        min: 1,
        max: 2000,
        step: 0,
        grid_num: 4,
        prettify_separator: ",",
        postfix: " Units",
        max_postfix: "+",
        force_edges: true,

  });
```

Comment: Good, clean solution.

Comment: Without validation, this is a really sketchy method. You're allowing anyone to inject values into your page's Javascript. What if they set `slide` to a malicious value or function?

Comment: @DaseinA thank you very much for the advice on which direction to take. I implemented that into my code and it works great. But now I have run into another problem, how do I make it to where when I land on this particular page from any other way besides this newly  created button the default FROM parameter should be the original 20?

Comment: @Jaser set the variable according with whether there is a url parameter or not. Use the length attribute to check for that: ``if (slide.length === 1) slide = default;``. Also perform some validation like the other guy said, so with the validation it would be: ``if (slide.length === 1 || isNaN(slide[slide.length - 1])) slide = default;``. Have a good one!

Comment: @DaseinA 

So here is where I am running into a problem:
So with the code you provided everything works properly except the certain product that is suppose to appear is not showing up. See my code on the link provided: http://codeshare.io/MeJQi

the products are connected with specific div tags with the html of the page. 

the main problem I am running into now is that the correct page based on the value is not showing. So when selecting that particular link, the show product should be "product25" and the default package should be "product1"

Comment: @jaser don't forget to set your own values to ``vals``. If your problem persisttry a new question based on the new problem.

Comment: @DaseinA I ended up creating another question, maybe you might be able to help. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879553/javascript-function-parameter-update

Answer (score 1):

Sharing JavaScript values between pages isn't really possible without storing it in some other form, and then parsing it back into JavaScript.

You could use URL parameters and then parse the incoming URL and import the default `from` value from there.

```
<a href='http://www.yoursite/?from=10'>Referral </a>
```

The downside to this is, obvious, anyone could just peek at your URL and then try and game your system (think what may happen if they set it to `?from=0` and you didn't protect against that). You'd also need to protect against injection attacks.

You could use `localStorage` to set a key after they've clicked that specific button, and then check `localStorage` for that key when loading the main page to get the expected default `from` value.

Set the value on click for the special link:

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){
  localStorage.setItem('fromValue', 10);
});
```

And retrieve it on load for the resulting page:

```
var fromValue = localStorage.getItem('fromValue')
if (fromValue) { /* adjust the slider's default from value*/ }
```

Comment: This seems like a more ephemeral use case, I would probably use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of `localStorage`. Likewise since we are tracking a link it might be good to remove the value after we check for it so that future visits to the page that don't come from that link use the normal default. Although using storage instead of passing it through the query string is more hidden, it will still need validation, if someone is trying to break the system they will be able to mess with the storage via the browser console.