# Javascript Function Parameter Update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running into a problem here trying to create a product showcase. Here is my Javascript code: http://codeshare.io/MeJQi

The slider for this code is for is here live at: http://therrd.com/screening.html#tenant-Screening

I can land on this specific page in two ways. One way is a button on another page that changes the default FROM of the slider to land on 15 Units which shows "Product25". Then the other way of landing on this page is where the slider is on default start value of 30 Unit and shows "Product1".

The problem I am having is changing the default product when I land on this page by clicking on the button on the other page, the slider updates but the showing product does not.

I would like to change the default value for the showProduct() based on the slider.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        init();

    });

    function init()
    {
        hideAllProducts();
        showProduct(1);


        vals = {max: 2000, min: 1, def: 20} //use your own values here for max min and def
        var param = window.location.href.split("slide=");
        slide = isNaN(param[param.length - 1]) ||
        param[param.length - 1] > vals.max ||
        param[param.length - 1] < vals.min ? vals.def : param[param.length - 1];
        //check if there is a url param, if it's a number and if it's in range

        $("#screeningSlider").ionRangeSlider({
            hide_min_max: true,
            keyboard: true,
            from: slide,
            min: 1,
            max: 2000,
            step: 0,
            grid_num: 4,
            prettify_separator: ",",
            postfix: " Units",
            max_postfix: "+",
            force_edges: true,
            onStart: function (value) {
                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = (value.from);
            },
            onChange: function (value) {
                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = (value.from);
            },
            onFinish: function (value) {
                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = (value.from);
            },
            onUpdate: function (value) {
                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = (value.from);
            }

        });


         $("#screeningSlider").on("change", function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                    value = $this.prop("value");
             productSliderOnChange(value);

       });


    }


    function productSliderOnChange(value)
    {
        $("#value").text(value);

        if(value == 0)
            hideAllProducts();
        else if ((value > 0) && (value <= 20))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(25);
        }
        else if ((value >= 21) && (value <= 60))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(1);
        }
        else if ((value >= 61) && (value <= 120))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(2);
        }
        else if ((value >= 121) && (value <= 180))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(3);
        }
        else if ((value >= 181) && (value <= 360))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(4);
        }
        else if ((value >= 361) && (value <= 580))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(5);
        }
        else if ((value >= 581) && (value <= 780))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(6);
        }
        else if ((value >= 781) && (value <= 980))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(7);
        }
        else if ((value >= 981) && (value <= 1180))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(8);
        }
        else if ((value >= 1181) && (value <= 1380))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(9);
        }
        else if ((value >= 1381) && (value <= 1580))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(10);
        }
        else if ((value >= 1581) && (value <= 1780))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(11);
        }
        else if ((value >= 1781) && (value <= 1980))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(12);
        }
        else if ((value > 1981))
        {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(13);
        }
        else {
            hideAllProducts();
            showProduct(1);
        }

    }

    function hideAllProducts()
    {
        $("#Product25").hide();
        $("#Product1").hide();
        $("#Product2").hide();
        $("#Product3").hide();
        $("#Product4").hide();
        $("#Product5").hide();
        $("#Product6").hide();
        $("#Product7").hide();
        $("#Product8").hide();
        $("#Product9").hide();
        $("#Product10").hide();
        $("#Product11").hide();
        $("#Product12").hide();
        $("#Product13").hide();
    }

    function showProduct(productId)
    {
        var product = "#Product" + productId;
        $(product).show();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here, instead of linking. At some point in the future, that link will break, and this question will be useless. If you post the code here, this question is more likely to remain useful to others in the future.

Comment: Ok thank you just updated.